# Did Miranda let her mother die on purpose?

Tags: plot-explanation, return-to-sender

In the movie *Return to Sender*, Miranda says to William:

> I watched my mother die. And she did a lot of things...

Earlier in the movie, it was said that she only *found* her mother after she had epilepsy seizure and wasn't able to get to her emergency medications in time.

I might be wrong, but to me it sounds like Miranda could have reached the emergency medications and save her mother, but **didn't do it on purpose**, to satisfy some curiosity by watching her mother die. Is this correct? This would also explain her total lack of sadness/grieving over the death of her mother, which her father mentions at some point.

Comment: Is that a literal quote, or a paraphrase? Because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Sender_(2015_film) says "Miranda tells him that she also poisoned her father's dog and allowed her mother to die." All too often questions feature badly remembered dialogue, while the actual dialogue is clear enough. Also, just quoting one line might lack context.

Comment: @BCdotWEB there are two quotes, yes, I didn't remember exact words so looked it up, found the one I used in two different sites. However, even the "allowed my mother to die" does not clearly imply she did it on purpose, i.e. she still might be saying it as part of self blaming over the mother's death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [transcript of the movie](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=return_to_sender_16864&p=15), she tells her rapist:

> William: What are you doing?
>
> Miranda: Surely you didn't think I'd forgotten that you came into my home and raped me?
>
> William: Did you make me sick?
>
> Miranda: No. The antifreeze made you sick.
>
> Miranda: I just provided it to you.
>
> Miranda: Oh, come on, I didn't give you any more than I gave Benny, and you got a good 70 pounds on him.

Benny was her father's dog, who had torn her dress earlier in the movie.

And then, [the dialog is](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=return_to_sender_16864&p=16):

> William: You're not gonna let me die.
>
> Miranda: I let my mother die, William.
>
> Miranda: She did a lot of things, but she didn't f*ck me from behind.

So, yes, she admits to her rapist, when he comes back to her home at the end, that she let her mother die and had killed her father's dog. She also admits to 'sticking a knife in a
guy', which was during an emergency tracheotomy.